# Animate anchor tags with Animate.css

Tags: html, css, animation

Hi i have the following

```
<p style="text-align:center;margin-top: 50px;"><a href="#" class="pictogram" style="position:relative;" id="arrow" >&#59236;</a></p>
```

I am using animate.css by Daniel Eden. If i add the class "animated shake" to the anchor tag, it doesn't work. But if i add it to the p tag, it works.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Probably because it's an inline element. Try making it `display: inline-block;`. Also why is your anchor style position relative?

Comment: I came accross another article that said to add relative positioning. Anyway, display:inline-block works perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Position relative means its a placeholder for it's children that are positioned absolute. It wouldn't do much in your case. It's safe to remove it again :)

Answer (score 0):

Transcribed from the comments, as it's solved for the OP;

Try adding it `display: inline-block;` and remove `position: relative;`.

Good luck!